# Como inserir valores que possuem "," como separador de decimal?

Tags: c#, input, razor, decimal

Olá, estou fazendo um cadastro de produto usando .Net Core 3.1 e estou com o seguinte problema:
No cadastro do produto existe um campo para inserir o valor do produto, porém ao inserir um valor com virgula, **300,50** por exemplo, ao sair do input, é retornado a seguinte mensagem :
[The field Preço must be a number.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzv33.png). O que posso fazer para conseguir inserir valores com "," ?

Código:

Classe Produto - campo Preco

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo <b>Preço</b> deve ser preenchido!")]
    [Display(Name = "Preço")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]       
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
```

Na classe Produto faço um **select * from produto id_Produto = @id_Produto** e os atributos são alimentados da seguinte maneira:

```
Produto produto = new Produto()
{
    ProdutoId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id_Produto"]),
    Descricao = rdr["descricao"].ToString(),
->  Preco = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["preco"]),
    Status = rdr["status"].ToString(),
    Id_Categoria = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id_Categoria"])

};
```

No **edit.cshtml** está assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Preco" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Preco" class="form-control"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Preco" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Existe um jeito utilizando `System.Globalization` de se alterar o separador de decimais, dá uma pesquisada. Uma solução prática: "35,50".Replace(",",".");

Comment: Boa noite Edney, obrigado pela ajuda! Fiz conforme o Leonardo falou, unica coisa de diferente que precisei fazer foi ao invés de usar o decimal.tryParse foi usar  Convert.ToDecimal.

Comment: PRECO.REPLACE(",","").REPLACE(",","."); E SEJA FELIZ

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o seu problema é você criar uma ViewModel e mudar o atributo para string, realizando a conversão para a classe Produto na controller, assim você consegue validar o seu campo sem mexer diretamente na sua Model.

Crie a classe ViewModel e mude seu **.cshtml** para recebe-la:

```
public class ProdutoViewModel
{
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Preco { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Id_Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

E na Controller, faça as seguintes alterações:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ProdutoViewModel produtoViewModel)
{
    // Caso não seja um número válido, será retornado 0
    decimal.TryParse(produtoViewModel.Preco.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(",","."), out decimal preco);

    Produto produto = new Produto()
    {
        ProdutoId = produtoViewModel.ProdutoId,
        Descricao = produtoViewModel.Descricao,
        Preco =  preco,
        Status = produtoViewModel.Status,
        Id_Categoria = produtoViewModel.Id_Categoria 
    };

    // Sua lógica para gravar no banco

    return View(produtoViewModel);
}
```

Perceba que substituímos o ponto por vazio, e a vírgula por ponto, assim quando receber o número "300,50" ele será transformado em "300.50", sendo um número válido.

Também fazemos o TryParse, para garantir que não seja disparado uma Exception caso não seja um número, sendo assim ele retornará o valor 0.

Não se esqueça de fazer a validação no HTML também, para garantir a consistência dos dados.

Comment: Boa noite Leonardo! deu quase certo sua solução apresentada, unico ponto foi no decimal.TryParse não sei porque estava pegando a string de valor "350.00" por exemplo, e juntando os numeros, ficando 35000, dai procurei na internet, uma solução que encontrei foi armazenar em uma string o resultado que era gerado pelo replace e depois passar para o atributo Preco do objeto produto, o seguinte: Convert.ToDecimal(preco,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat), aonde o parametro preco é a string que armazena o valor 350.00